# How can I make Mac Mail mark messages as read automatically?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, apple-mail

I have rules set up that correctly filter messages into different folders, but for some reason no messages are marked as read.

Comment: Perhaps the order of the rules matter.
Have you tried mark first as read, then move to folder?

Comment: Yes--the program actually re-orders the actions after you save the rule. I suppose I could make two rules for the same condition....

Comment: @mefepe I'm using the exact same actions but my rules move first, then mark as read. Works like a charm since forever.